# Show logged in user's data in profile.php

Tags: php, pdo

```
    <?php


  require('db.php');


  $_SESSION['sloggedIn']="yes";
  $data1['first_name'] = $_SESSION['sfirstname'];
  $data1['email'] = $_SESSION['semail'];  
  
  $sqlQuery = "SELECT first_name, email FROM otium where id = :id";

  file_put_contents('log/DBErrors.txt', 'Connection: '.'rivi8'.$sqlQuery."\n", FILE_APPEND);
  $kysely1 = $DBH->prepare($sqlQuery);
  $kysely1->execute($data1);

  // Loop the recordset $rs
  // Each row will be made into an array ($row) using mysqli_fetch_array
  //while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) {

    // Write the value of the column FirstName (which is now in the array $row)
    echo $sqlQuery['first_name'] . "<br />";
    echo $sqlQuery['email'] . "<br />";

  //}

  ?>
```

**First time doing this php and i would like to print out user's logged in data, i have this code but is not working! please help**

Comment: `$sqlQuery` is clearly a simple string containing your SQL. Why would you expect it to to magically become an array, or to contain the _results_ of your query? None of the rest of your code modifies that variable in any way. And...any PDO tutorial would show you how to get the results of your query... https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#foreach is just one. There are also examples in the manual. Did you do any basic research?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As general advice, I'd recommend reading [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some pointers on writing a good question. For specific advice, I'd recommend studying what it is you should actually supply to the [`execute`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute) method. You also seem to have mixed `PDO` and `mysqli` extensions.

Comment: You also never bind anything to `:id`. The `$data1` array you're using only contains `first_name` and `email` (which are not placeholders in your query). There are many fundamental issues here. You should go through some PHP + MySQL tutorials and read the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$sqlQuery` is just string variable containing query, you can't expect it to be a array.

I guess you already got firstName and email from session then there is no need of executing sql query, just printing the session will make your job done.

```
echo $_SESSION['first_name'] . "<br />";
echo $_SESSION['email'] . "<br />";
```